# Want to match the string from list of entries and select all entries after the matching string using ANT script

Tags: ant

I have list of entries in a text file,

1.0.1
1.0.2
1.0.5
2.0.3
3.0.4
4.0.0.5

If input given as 1.0.5 all the entries after 1.0.5 shall be selected and entered in new text file. Can this be done using ANT script? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

Use the Ant [`<copy>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task with a [`<filterchain>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) that removes all lines before the match.

```
<property name="in.file" value="input.txt" />
<property name="out.file" value="output.txt" />

<property name="match.str" value="1.0.5" />

<copy file="${in.file}" tofile="${out.file}">
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <filetokenizer/>
      <replaceregex pattern=".*\n(${match.str})\n"
                    flags="s"
                    replace="\1${line.separator}" />
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

If you don't want the match string included in the output file, change to

```
      <replaceregex pattern=".*\n(${match.str})\n"
                    flags="s"
                    replace="" />
```

The [`<filetokenizer>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#filetokenizer) treats all the lines of the file as one string, so this approach will not work well with large files.

You will see issues if the line separators in your file are different to the default in the operating system hosting your build.

You could also use the [`<replaceregexp>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task, but that will update the file in place, rather than writing to a new file.

Comment: Thanks it worked. And replaceregexp can also be used as you mentioned by creating copy of the file.